# A first chance exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting below following errors:

1. A first chance exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll
2. Additional information: The "SendUsing" configuration value is invalid.

Below is my C# code:

```
public void getdata()
{
    lbl_errorDob.Visible = false;
    lbl_wishes.Visible = false;
    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in Employeedob.Rows)
    {
        if (((CheckBox)gvr.FindControl("CheckBox2")).Checked == true)
        {
            value = "Success";
            Label lb = (Label)gvr.FindControl("lbl_Email");
            Label Name = (Label)gvr.FindControl("lbl_Ename");
            MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
            mailMsg.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;
            string strBody = "";
            string image = "http://xyzdotcom/images/bg_login.gif";
            strBody = "<html><body  background-repeat:no-repeat;\" > ";
            strBody = strBody + "<br><br>";
            strBody = strBody + "<table width='600' align='center'><tr><td> If you are not able to view this mailer properly,please <a href='http://xyzdotcom/birthdaywishes.html?Name=" + Name.Text + "&from=" + Session["EmpName"].ToString() + "'>click here</a><td><tr><table>";
            strBody = strBody + "<br><br>";
            mailMsg.From = Session["EmailId"].ToString();
            //  mailMsg.From = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AdminEmailAddress"];
            mailMsg.To = lb.Text;
            mailMsg.Subject = "MANY MORE HAPPY RETURNS OF THE DAY";
            mailMsg.Body = strBody;
            SmtpMail.Send(mailMsg);
            lbl_wishes.Visible = true;
            lbl_errorDob.Visible = false;

        }
        else
        {
            if (value == "")
            {
                lbl_errorDob.Visible = true;
                lbl_wishes.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

protected void lnkbtn_SendMyWishes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getdata();
}
```

I used below namespaces:

```
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Mail;
```

Comment: try setting port, host and credentials before send function.

Comment: Would you please share what are you setting on SmtpMail ?? Are you enabling SSL and did you turn off firewall + antivirus. Or can you share with us where exactly you are getting this error. Thanks